"Oh no" something has gone wrong with neither TTY access nor recovery mode after Upgrade to 24.04
I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 and after a system reboot, only a white background page with message "Oh no, something has gone wrong" appears and I neither have access to a TTY using ALT + CTRL + F(x)(getting black screen with blinking cursor) nor the recovery mode(it's stuck at an entirely black screen) is working.
Is there any chance I can recover from this situation?
